# library for integer arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, static-libraries

Maybe it's a dumb question but:
I'm looking for a library for the classic functions on arrays of Integers (sorting, searching ...) in C, does anyone know a good one ?

I could rewrite those functions but, to be honest, I'm quite lazy.

More generally, is there a list of known libraries somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For sorting you already have the standard function [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: + [`bsearch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch).

Comment: Both `qsort` and `bsearch` are in the cstdlib c header

Comment: thanks, and is there a list of known libraries?
Cause without knowing the function name, it's quite difficult to find the adequat library.